# I can't connect to SQL when I open a VPN - Swift

Tags: swift

I pull data from MSSQL. When the login process matches with the username and password I have withdrawn from the database, login takes place. When I log in from Turkey are currently doing smooth entry. But when I turn on the VPN, I cannot log in. That's why I'm eating red when installing the app on the Apple Store. Do I need to take any action to allow entry from abroad?

```
 client!.connect("...", username: "...", password: "...", database: "...") {
                            success in
                            if success {
                                client?.execute("SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE form_eposta LIKE '\(eMailText)' And ... LIKE '\(md5Data)'") {
                                    results in
                                  if results == nil {
                                      let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Giriş Başarısız", message: "Kullanıcı Adını veya Şifresi yanlış lütfen tekrar deneyiniz.", preferredStyle: .alert)
                                                            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Tamam", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
                           self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

                                  }
       if results != nil {
        for table in results as AnyObject? as! NSArray {
             for row in table as AnyObject? as! NSArray {

                for column in row as! NSDictionary {
                  self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginSuccess", sender: column.value)

                                            }
```

Comment: You are connecting directly to a SQL Server database across the Internet? That's almost certainly never going to work as intended. For a start, by default, SQL Server uses port 1433 which is almost certainly blocked at your firewall. Secondly, there's the security implications of random people on the internet being able to connect directly to an SQL database and execute queries. You need to think in terms of writing a REST application to expose only those only the queries your app needs and have your app make HTTP requests to it.

Comment: But it works fine when I try it from my own country, I have this problem when I open vpn and try to enter from another country @JeremyP

Comment: It could be the VPN itself blocking the port.